# Ceiling fan install - orientation of mounting bracket to slope of ceiling

Tags: ceiling-fan, studs

I'm replacing a  light fixture with a fan/light using a down rod mount on an angled ceiling. The frame studs run parallel with the slope of the ceiling. Manufacturer notes to install mounting bracket socket so that the open end (the open side where the ball slides in) of the bracket faces towards the high end of the ceiling.  Because the ceiling studs are only 2" wide this isn't possible,[ceiling fixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZxMm.jpg)

So in my image, to the right is upwards on the slope of the ceiling.

The best I can do here is have the open side 45 degrees to the left or right of the slope.

Is that sufficient or is there a better way to do this? Can I screw an adaptor into the stud and then attach the bracket to the adaptor?

I really would like to use the existing hole in my ceiling and not cut a new hole and use a race box

Comment: I'd sister a short length of 2x4 on either side of the existing joist. That way you don't have to make a new hole, and you can face the gap in the bracket uphill.

Comment: Good suggestion. Curious have you ever seen a crossbar used?